# Youtube on Android - how to check what protocol it uses?

Tags: android, http, youtube, protocols, rtsp

Can anyone tell me, how can I check what protocol is in use, when I watch video by Youtube application on Android? I wonder if it is normal HTTP, or RTSP? I tried to find some information about this, but with no results... Thanks for advance!

Comment: Use a Packet sniffer like Wireshark. Then filter the packets that originate from your android phone with the source as your Android Phones' IP and the destination as youtube.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wireshark to view the packets, but YouTube probably use SSL. I suggest using Burp SSL MITM to view the SSL packets, assuming YouTube app don't use SSL pinning.